# vtkScalarBar with non linear labels

Tags: c++, vtk

Is there any way to get the scalar bar to not automatically set my labels to a linear value?

I would like to access the labels table and change myself the value so it follows my own formula.

```
// scalar bar
_hueLut = vtkLookupTable::New();
_hueLut->SetNumberOfTableValues(100);
_hueLut->SetTableRange(0, 100);
_hueLut->SetTableValue(0, 0, 0, 1);
_hueLut->SetTableValue(1, 0, 1, 0);
//etc...
_hueLut->Build();


_scalarBar = vtkScalarBarActor::New();
_scalarBar->SetLookupTable(_hueLut);
_scalarBar->SetTitle("logarithm scalar bar");
_scalarBar->SetNumberOfLabels(5);
_scalarBar->SetLabelFormat("%5.4g");
```

The problem is that my scalar bar labels seems to show the value 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100. I want to be able to change the labels value. For example: 0, 10, 25, 50, 100.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying your own function is not supported directly, only linear and logarithmic scale are implemented in `vtkLookupTable`, which is the class for your scalar bar value-color mapping.
However, you can easily derive from `vtkLookupTable` and override `Build()` method to implement arbitrary mapping. See `vtkWindowLevelLookupTable` for a good example.

If all you need is log transform, then set `SetScaleToLog10()` on your 
lut. And make sure the range is positive.

There are 3 options for the ramp function, which lets you adjust how the color changes, color "sensitivity" you could say. S-curve (default), which gives you more gradual at the ends of the range, linear and sqrt. See docs for more details.

HTH,

Miro